# Pandas error when reading key node that is also an object

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple JSON that looks like this

```
{"dV":201,"data1":{"test":"ok","data2":[{"id":1,"summary":{"openingBalance":"-7583.48","totalCredits":"1203.52"},"additionalDetails":{"email":"XXXXXXXX@outlook.com","phone":"XXXX XXX 333"}}]}}
```

I am normalizing this JSON by doing the following

```
import pandas as pd
textInJSON = '{"dV":201,"data1":{"test":"ok","data2":[{"id":1,"summary":{"openingBalance":"-7583.48","totalCredits":"1203.52"},"additionalDetails":{"email":"XXXXXXXX@outlook.com","phone":"XXXX XXX 333"}}]}}'
d = pd.read_json(textInJSON)
df = pd.json_normalize(d['data1']['data2'])
```

Why I get an error when doing something like this?

```
df['additionalDetails']
```

but when I do something like the line below I can retrieve the information (XXXXXXXX@outlook.com):

```
df['additionalDetails.email']
```

Because I thought I should be able to do:

```
df['additionalDetails']['email']
```

Comment: Just print your df and you will see all the column names

Comment: `df['additionalDetails']` is not a dictionary you can't access using `df['additionalDetails']['email']`

Comment: you should read `orient` argument in [pandas.read_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html#pandas-read-json)

Answer (score 0):

If you print your dataframe

```
print(df)
```

you will se that what you are getting is actually this:

```
id summary.openingBalance summary.totalCredits additionalDetails.email additionalDetails.phone
01               -7583.48              1203.52 XXXXXXXX@outlook.com    XXXX XXX 333
```

Which tells me that your `summary` is actually a dictionary like.

So when you do `pd.json_normalize(d['data1']['data2'])` pandas need to somehow translate that nesting to the dataframe.

Thats why the values need to be accessed the way you shown.

Here is a better visualisation of you data:

```
textInJSON = '''{
    "dV": 201,
    "data1": {
        "test": "ok",
        "data2": [{
            "id": 1,
            "summary": {
                "openingBalance": "-7583.48",
                "totalCredits": "1203.52"
            },
            "additionalDetails": {
                "email": "XXXXXXXX@outlook.com",
                "phone": "XXXX XXX 333"
            }
        }]
    }
}'''
```